# Recycler View inside a NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I have a few Horizontally scrollable Recycler views inside a NestedScrollView. How do I disable only the vertical scroll in the recycler views and pass this vertical touch to the parent NestedScrollView?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="192dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@color/toolbarScrim"
        app:title=" "
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/ArticleImg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/article_img"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffe5e5e5"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context="com.global.jet.global.BizForum.ArticleView"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_article_view">


        <RelativeLayout

            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/view2">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_width="64dp"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView9"
                android:background="@drawable/rv"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/link"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:id="@+id/ArticlePostName"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView9"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView9" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_add_black_18dp"
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="31 oct 2015,12:49-"
                android:id="@+id/ArticleDate"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ArticlePostName"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView9"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView9" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/link"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:id="@+id/ArticleDes"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ArticleDate"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView9"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView9" />

            <ImageView
                android:background="@drawable/clock_ic"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_width="18dp"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView15"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ArticleDate"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ArticleDate"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ArticleDate" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="3 min read"
                android:id="@+id/ArticleTime"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView15"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView15"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView15" />

            <View
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/grey_333"
                android:id="@+id/textView17"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView9"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView9"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView9"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button3" />             
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
     android:id="@+id/scrollableview"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you set an touch listener for the `RecyclerView` and detect whether it is horizontal or vertical scroll. Return `true` when it is horizontal and return `false` when it is vertical.

```
RecyclerView rv = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
rv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // your logic here
    }
});
```

Reference - [View.OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html#onTouch%28android.view.View,%20android.view.MotionEvent%29)

Comment: Yes this is the logic involved. But can you please help me with some code?